# Calculating Formula After Text Paste

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I have a formula that constructs a vlookup function while drawing the file path from a date input from the user, next I have a macro that takes the results of this formula and pastes them in Cell C6.

```
=("=" & "IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP($A6," & "'I:\CM\PC\A\TR\AT\"&TEXT(C$5,"yyyy")&"\"&TEXT(C$5,"mmmmmmmmmmm")&"\["&TEXT(C$5,"mmm")&TEXT(C$5,"d")&".xlsm]Violations Count'!$A:$B"&",2,FALSE)),"""",VLOOKUP($A6,"&"'I:\CM\PC\A\TR\AT\"&TEXT(C$5,"yyyy")&"\"&TEXT(C$5,"mmmmmmmmmmm")&"\["&TEXT(C$5,"mmm")&TEXT(C$5,"d")&".xlsm]Violations Count'!$A:$B"&",2,FALSE))")
```

The trouble I am having is finding a way for VBA to activate the formula instead of having it sit there in a text format as:

```
=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP($A6,'I:\CM\PC\A\TR\AT\2016\December\[Dec5.xlsm]Violations Count'!$A:$B,2,FALSE)),"",VLOOKUP($A6,'I:\CM\PC\A\TR\AT\2016\December\[Dec5.xlsm]Violations Count'!$A:$B,2,FALSE))
```

Afterward I just have a macro autofill it down for the other names between column A6:A37.

If anyone can help me with VBA activating the cell, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the value of a cell (which might contain a text string) you use something like:

```
someVariableEtc = Range("A1").Value
```

If you want to set a Cell's formula using VBA, you would use something like:

```
Range("C6").Formula = "some text string"
```

Combining the two, you could come up with something like:

```
Range("C6").Formula = Range("A1").Value
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, learning new stuff every day with VBA haha only been using it a ton for the past 4 weeks.

Answer (score 0):

[Look this up](http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=52372). The evaluate function might be what you're looking for. The simplest way to use it is wrapping an expression in square brackets [].

Comment: Thanks for the link! Gonna look more into evaluate and see what is possible with it. YowE3K's answer solved the problem for future reference too.